# React Redux Failed prop type: Required prop was not specified

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm having some problems with a failed prop type trying to learn Redux with react.
The thing is I want to create a note with a title and some text, but because of the Failed prop type only the title will display.

The warnings:

```
warning.js:36 Warning: Failed prop type: Required prop `notes[0].text` was not specified in `NoteList`.
in NoteList (created by Connect(NoteList))
in Connect(NoteList) (created by App)
in div (created by App)
in App
in Provider

warning.js:36 Warning: Failed prop type: Required prop `text` was not specified in `Note`.
in Note (created by NoteList)
in NoteList (created by Connect(NoteList))
in Connect(NoteList) (created by App)
in div (created by App)
in App
in Provider
```

ListNotes.js:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import NotesList from '../components/NotesList'

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        notes: state.notes
    }
}

const ListNotes = connect(
    mapStateToProps
)(NotesList)

export default ListNotes
```

NotesList.js:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import Note from './Note'

const NoteList = ({ notes }) => {
    return (
        <ul>
            {notes.map(note =>
                 <note
                     key={note.id}
                     {...note}
                 />
            )}
        </ul>
    )
}


NoteList.propTypes = {
    notes: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
        id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        text: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }).isRequired).isRequired
}

export default NoteList
```

Note.js:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'

const Note = ({title, text}) => {
    return (
        <li>
            <h1>{title}</h1>
            <p>{text}</p>
        </li>
    )
}

Note.propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    text: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}

export default Note
```

Comment: `<note key={note.id} {...note}/>` don't you mean `<Note key={note.id} {...note}/>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what’s in `state.notes`. You could log it or set a breakpoint somewhere and use your browser’s debugger.

It seems the objects in that array don’t have a `text` property or it’s set to `undefined` or `null`. You might have a typo where that value should be set.

If you’re seeing the titles then everything else seems to be in order.

Comment: yup, just me getting tired. sometimes I just need someone to tell me I have a typo somewhere.